# Collections.sort() on nested property values

Tags: java, sorting, nullpointerexception, nested-properties

I am working on sorting feature for a data table. I have JSF Web Controller:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SearchPlayerController implements Serializable {

    private List<Player> playerList;

    @EJB
    PlayerFacade playerFacade;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (playerList == null) {
            playerList = playerFacade.findAll();
        }
    }

    // getters and setters
    *
    *
    *
}
```

In this Controller I have a sorting method:

```
public String sortDataByClubName(final String dir) {
    Collections.sort(playerList, (Player a, Player b) -> {
        if(a.getClubId().getClubName()
            .equals(b.getClubId().getClubName())) {
            return 0;
        } else if(a.getClubId().getClubName() == null) {
            return -1;
        } else if(b.getClubId().getClubName() == null) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            if(dir.equals("asc")) {
                return a.getClubId().getClubName()
                    .compareTo(b.getClubId().getClubName());
            } else {
                return b.getClubId().getClubName()
                    .compareTo(a.getClubId().getClubName());
            }
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

After invoking the sort on page view, it throws `NullPointerException`. I think the main reason is that inside the `Comparator` it can't read the value of `clubName` that should be accessible after getting Club object. Is there any possibility to compare values of nested properties?

Comment: This is in no way jsf related.  Try in a plain java class with just a main method. And mentioning where the NOW occurs its the least you could do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be sorting only on `Player.getClubId().getClubName()`. It seems like both `getClubId()` and `getClubName()` should be checked for null. This is how I would do it:

```
public class PlayerComparator implements Comparator<Player> {
    private String dir; // Populate with constructor
    public int compare(Player a, Player b) {
        int result = nullCheck(a.getClubId(), b.getClubId());
        if(result != 0) {
            return result;
        }
        String aname = a.getClubId().getClubName();
        String bname = b.getClubId().getClubName();
        result = nullCheck(aname, bname);
        if(result != 0) {
            return result;
        }
        result = aname.compareTo(bname);
        if("asc".equals(dir)) {   // No NPE thrown if `dir` is null
            result = -1 * result;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private int nullCheck(Object a, Object b) {
        if(a == null) { return -1; }
        if(b == null) { return 1; }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Och, yes, you’re right! I have completely forgotten that player.getClubId() can also return null! Thank you very much, sir!